# Why do you think I get this error when I precompile in rails 5 - "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@babel/preset-react'"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, babeljs, webpacker

I have a Ruby on Rails 5 app running inside docker, when I precompile I get an error about "@babel/preset-react". Please help me on how to resolve this.

When I run this precompile command:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get the error below:

```
Compiling...
Compilation failed:
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@babel/preset-react' imported from /home/app/webapp/my-app/babel-virtual-resolve-base.js
    at new NodeError (/home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:2240:5)
    at packageResolve (/home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:2776:9)
    at moduleResolve (/home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:2804:18)
    at defaultResolve (/home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:2835:13)
    at /home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:2855:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:45:103)
    at _next (/home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:46:194)
    at /home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:46:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:46:97
    at resolve (/home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:2847:19)
    at /home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/import-meta-resolve.js:27:38
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/import-meta-resolve.js:15:103)
    at _next (/home/app/webapp/my-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/import-meta-resolve.js:16:194) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

I already tried the 2 commands below but I still get the error when I precompile.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react

yarn add @babel/preset-react --dev
```

Here are some more info about my environment:

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Ruby on Rails version: Rails 5.2.8.1

Webpacker gem: webpacker (5.4.3)

yarn --version: 1.22.19

node -v: v18.13.0

npm --version: 9.4.0